# Sublime Text 3 ABAP Syntax Highlighting / Color scheme

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, abap, color-scheme, sublimetext3

I am looking for a Color Scheme in Sublime Text 3 for ABAP to highlight the syntax.

I have found [this](https://github.com/PavelJaros/ABAP-Sublime-Plugin) so far, but it does not work with version 3. It is supposed to be used with version 2.

**EDIT:**

This is how the Theme looks:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried it with version 3? I don't have any ABAP files to test it with, but looking over the package's contents there's nothing there that wouldn't work with ST3.

Comment: Yeah I did. I downloaded it, created the ABAP folder under `Browse Packages ...` and also selected it as the Color Scheme. You can use some code from here http://www.4ap.de/pages/abap/syntax/codeschnipsel.php

Comment: thanks for the link, I'll get back to you and see what I can do. In the meantime, if you want please check out my [Neon Color Scheme](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme) (Package Control link), also available [on GitHub](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-color-scheme) for manual install. My main goal in designing it was to make as many languages as possible look as good as possible, and while I didn't specifically target ABAP, from a brief view of the `.tmLanguage` definition file, Neon should work fine. See if you like it, and I'll get back to you on ST3.

Comment: I already have it. [See](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067781/change-add-syntax-highlighting-for-language-in-sublime-3) It doesn't really support ABAP though.

Comment: Worked here, on sublime text 3.

Comment: @felipecrp I tried it again and it still does not work. I also uploaded a screenshot.

Comment: From the screenshot, the file is detected as "Plain Text". Can you manually set syntax to ABAP and see if the syntax highlighting works?

Comment: @Niklas Click on the bottom right of the window and choose the correct ABAP syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 5):

To use ABAP Syntax highlight from [ABAP-Sublime-Plugin](https://github.com/PavelJaros/ABAP-Sublime-Plugin) in Sublime Text 3 you need to follow this steps:

1. Steps described in "How to install it?" section on Github repository:

   - Open your Package folder. The easiest way to identify the Package folder is to go to ST2 main menu: Preferences -> Browse Packages...
   - Manualy create ABAP folder under your Package folder: ...\Packages\ABAP
   - Extract the content of zip archive into the ABAP folder (!!only the files without ABAP-Sublime-Plugin-master folder!!).
2. Delete file `package-metadata.json` from ABAP folder. This file is used by Package Control Plugin and this file is not compatible with Package Control in Sublime Text 3.
3. Choose ABAP code highlight scheme:

   - If the file you are editing has .abp extension, syntax highlighting works automaticaly
   - Or click on the bottom right corner in the ST3 window a choose ABAP
   - Or open command window: Ctrl+Shift+P -> Enter "Abap" -> Hit "Enter"

Comment: i installed on my sublime text 3, but the go_to_definition or F12 doesn't work anymore, any idea how to get it back?