# How do I set custom HTML tag highlighting in a Sublime Text 3 theme?

Tags: html, themes, sublimetext, sublimetext3, color-scheme

I modified the existing ST3 theme file so that the `id` tag attribute will be highlighted with a specific color format, and it works perfectly:

```
<dict>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>CSS: #id</string>
  <key>scope</key>
  <string>entity.other.attribute-name.id.html</string>
  <key>settings</key>
  <dict>
    <key>fontStyle</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>foreground</key>
    <string>#99ff00</string>
    <key>background</key>
    <string>#0066ff</string>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

The problem is that I also want to have specific highlighting for the `"class"`, `"style"` and `"name"` attributes (ideally each with a different color). But simply changing the `entity.other.attribute-name` string does **not** highlight the specific text inside the tags.   My tag attributes are set to default as green color already, and that works also:

```
<dict>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>Tag attribute</string>
  <key>scope</key>
  <string>entity.other.attribute-name</string>
  <key>settings</key>
  <dict>
    <key>fontStyle</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>foreground</key>
    <string>#A6E22E</string>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

How can I change tag attributes other than "id"?  I would like `"class"`, `"style"` and `"name"`attributes to also have a back highlight just like "id" does, but so far, only "id" gets highlighted no matter what I've tried. What do I need to change?  Thanks!

Comment: answer found in [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067781/change-add-syntax-highlighting-for-a-language-in-sublime-2-3)

Answer (score 0):

You can target them with `entity.other.attribute-name.html`