# Is there a root keyword in JavaScript or why does Sublime display it like this?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, keyword

I used a variable called `root` in a recent JavaScript project, and Sublime Text 3 displayed it like this:

[image: Screenshot of code snippet showing "root" highlighted by text editor]

So I'm wondering if there is a `root` keyword in JavaScript, and if so what does it do... Otherwise I'd like to know a way to stop Sublime Text from displaying it differently... The console, however, says `ReferenceError: root is not defined` when I type it in there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`root` used to be a variable in Node.js however it was [deprecated](https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/Breaking-changes-between-v5-and-v6?utm_source=nodeweekly&utm_medium=email#globals) in v6.

**UPDATE**:
The old URL doesn't work anymore, so I've updated it with the Internet Archive's Wayback Machine's [version](https://web.archive.org/web/20170428234640/https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/Breaking-changes-between-v5-and-v6) of it, also [here's](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/1838) the merge request with the change.

The declaration comes from [this](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/blob/master/JavaScript/JavaScript.sublime-syntax#L1389) file in Sublime.

**UPDATE**:
To remove the syntax rule, install `PackageResourceViewer` as per the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21542563/771466) and then open up the `JavaScript.sublime-syntax` file, find the word root (there's currently only one) and remove it (and the following `|` character).
Note that you'll need to run Sublime as an administrator on Windows in order to edit the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but where can I change the file for me?

Comment: @AntonBallmaier, I've updated the answer with instructions to stop Sublime from highlighting the word `root`

Answer (score -1):

It seems root is not a keyword of javascript:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Comment: Im down voting because w3schools can be anything but a a reliable javascript reference

Comment: Downvoted. Even disregarding the fact that "w3schools" is a poor JavaScript resource, it's by no stretch an authority as it neither participates in devising, commenting on or publishing JavaScript (or ECMAScript) specifications, hence it simply cannot rightfully be used as a reference. In other words, it doesn't matter what w3schools.com says on the subject.

Comment: @amn Those all apply to MDN as well, yet MDN is much more reliable, as a public wiki with peer review. It's just that w3schools happens to be terrible.