# Change sublime text 3 java variables color

Tags: java, sublimetext3

I'm trying to modify the color of variables in Sublime Text 3, the language is java.

I've tried the tmTheme Editor, modifying the package files in the installation folder but I just can't change it as i change the values but they never appear on the text editor as I want.

Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

**Preferences > Color scheme** might be what you're looking for?

Comment: No, that only changes the color scheme in general, not individual parts of the code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067781/change-add-syntax-highlighting-for-a-language-in-sublime-2-3    Check this